# What is the reason of getting different accuracies from the same program?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I try to calculate the accuracy of my tagger. But I always get different accuracy when I run the program although I use the same training and development data. What is the reason behind this result? Thanks in advance.

```
with open('train.txt') as f:
training_sentences = list(splitter(f))

with open('develop.txt') as f:
test_sentences = list(splitter(f))

.
.
.
SOME FEATURES AS A LIST OF DICTS
.
.
.

def transform_to_dataset(training_sentences):
    X, y = [], []
    for tagged in training_sentences:
        for index in range(len(tagged)):
            X.append(features(untag(tagged), index))
            y.append(tagged[index][1])
    return X, y

X, y = transform_to_dataset(training_sentences)


clf = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', DictVectorizer(sparse=False)),
    ('classifier', DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy'))
])

clf.fit(X, y)  

X_test, y_test = transform_to_dataset(test_sentences)

print "Accuracy:", clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: set random seed to a fixed value?

Comment: Am I using something random ?

Comment: Yes you probably are: per http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree "Such algorithms cannot guarantee to return the globally optimal decision tree. This can be mitigated by training multiple trees in an ensemble learner, where the features and samples are randomly sampled with replacement."

Comment: Ohh thanks, I forgot to change DecisionTreeClassifier to LogisticRegression().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sklearn` `DecisionTreeClassifier` uses a random number generator to determine its [splitting](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L657). If you want to guarantee the same results for each run, set the [`random_state`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) parameter of the classifier